# Unspecified error in QGIS model builder

Tags: qgis, qgis-modeler

I'm trying to build a model to do a series of vector processes to cluster points, take the mean coordinates of those clusters, then measure the distance between each point and its mean coordinate as well as the distance between the mean coordinates and another point.

I've already had to build 2 different models because there's no way (as far as I can tell) to get the mean coordinates of the clusters rather than the entire algorithm output. Now every time I try to run the model I get an error without any code or information. This same thing happens with different processes and in both models I'm working on. "Error encountered while running (algorithm)."

[image: The first model breaks] [image: THe model in question] [image: The second model also breaks]

The models are super simple, so I expect I'm just missing something really basic. I'm self-taught w/ QGIS. I updated from 3.26 to 3.28 while trying to find a solution, and neither one worked. Tried the stable 3.22 version, and I got a different error. I don't know what it means, and not sure if this is progress or getting worse.

[image: Traceback error.]

The model code is below and some sample data can be found [here](https://github.com/wdossett/turbo-goggles/blob/76ee54f0f714fbca24368a6972c342ebc16ae5f4/files%20for%20troubleshooting.gpkg).

```py
from qgis.core import QgsProcessing
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingAlgorithm
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingMultiStepFeedback
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingParameterVectorLayer
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingParameterField
import processing


class Model(QgsProcessingAlgorithm):

    def initAlgorithm(self, config=None):
        self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterVectorLayer('warehouses', 'Warehouses', types=[QgsProcessing.TypeVectorPoint], defaultValue=None))
        self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterVectorLayer('delivery_sites', 'Delivery Sites', types=[QgsProcessing.TypeVectorPoint], defaultValue=None))
        self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterField('warehouse_name', 'Warehouse Name', type=QgsProcessingParameterField.Any, parentLayerParameterName='warehouses', allowMultiple=False, defaultValue='NVILLAGE'))
        self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterField('site_warehouse', 'Site Warehouse', type=QgsProcessingParameterField.Any, parentLayerParameterName='delivery_sites', allowMultiple=False, defaultValue='Warehouse'))

    def processAlgorithm(self, parameters, context, model_feedback):
        # Use a multi-step feedback, so that individual child algorithm progress reports are adjusted for the
        # overall progress through the model
        feedback = QgsProcessingMultiStepFeedback(3, model_feedback)
        results = {}
        outputs = {}

        # Split vector layer
        alg_params = {
            'FIELD': parameters['warehouse_name'],
            'FILE_TYPE': 0,  # gpkg
            'INPUT': parameters['warehouses'],
            'PREFIX_FIELD': True,
            'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
        }
        outputs['SplitVectorLayer'] = processing.run('native:splitvectorlayer', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)

        feedback.setCurrentStep(1)
        if feedback.isCanceled():
            return {}

        # Split sites
        alg_params = {
            'FIELD': parameters['site_warehouse'],
            'FILE_TYPE': 0,  # gpkg
            'INPUT': parameters['delivery_sites'],
            'PREFIX_FIELD': True,
            'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
        }
        outputs['SplitSites'] = processing.run('native:splitvectorlayer', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)

        feedback.setCurrentStep(2)
        if feedback.isCanceled():
            return {}

        # Matrix from layers
        alg_params = {
            'INPUT_END_FIELD': '',
            'INPUT_END_LAYER': outputs['SplitSites']['OUTPUT'],
            'INPUT_PROFILE': 0,  # driving-car
            'INPUT_PROVIDER': 0,  # openrouteservice
            'INPUT_START_FIELD': '',
            'INPUT_START_LAYER': outputs['SplitVectorLayer']['OUTPUT'],
            'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
        }
        outputs['MatrixFromLayers'] = processing.run('ORS Tools:matrix_from_layers', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)
        return results

    def name(self):
        return 'model'

    def displayName(self):
        return 'model'

    def group(self):
        return ''

    def groupId(self):
        return ''

    def createInstance(self):
        return Model()
```

Comment: "Unspecific error" is always difficult to reproduce... and to help you, we should be able to reproduce the error. So we should start to re-build your exact model, based on the information and screenshot you provided. As this is cumbersome, it would be good if you could share your data (at least a sample) + project and model.

Comment: Right, I've included the python code for the model and some sample data. Sorry about that.